# How to get input value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to get the input value when clicking a button like this:

This is the variable that I'm using to store the value:

```
let textInput = React.createRef();
```

And this is the way I'm doing it:

```
<input ref={textInput} type="tel" placeholder="Número de teléfono"></input>
```

Then, I have a button:

```
<button onClick={fetchRequest} className="btn btn-default">Comprobar teléfono</button>
```

that calls this:

```
const fetchRequest = useCallback(() => {
    database.collection('UsuariosDev').where('Telefono', '==', 
      textInput.current.value).get()
        .then(response => {
            const fetchedUsers = [];
            response.forEach(document => {
                const fetchedUser = {
                    id: document.id,
                    ...document.data()
                };
                fetchedUsers.push(fetchedUser);
                console.log(fetchedUser)
            });
            setUsers(fetchedUsers);
            if (fetchedUsers.length !== 0) {
                setTitle('✔️')
            } else {
                setTitle('❌')
            }
        })
}, [])
```

Basically everytime I click the button I make a firestore query. The first time it works just fine, but the second time I click the button I get an error that says that textInput is null:

> TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating
> 'textInput.current.value')

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here is that [useCallback](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback) creates a memoized callback. And as you provided an empty dependency array `[]`, the same function will always be returned.

In your case, it's problematic because by using `createRef`, you create a new ref everytime the component re-renders.

Thus, your `fetchRequest` callback isn't aware of the new ref when the component re-renders (presumably when you update the state using `setUsers()` or `setTitle()`).

The solution here would be to either:

- Set `textInput` as a dependency of your `useCallback`, so that it's aware of the newly created ref

```
const fetchRequest = useCallback(() => {
...
}, [textInput])
```

OR

- use [useRef](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref) instead of `createRef` so that the ref is always the same, even after re-rendering.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like this is being caused by the reference to the input DOM element being lost between renders, and the memoised `useCallback` isn't helping.

---

Rather than using `ref={textInput}`, you should use `onBlur` or `onChange` to update a state variable when the contents of the input is changed. [See the React docs on form elements](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html).

This makes a nicer separation, and will make sure that the data is accessible by the callback function, rather than it trying to access a DOM node and extracting its current value.

---

You also probably don't want to be using `useCallback`, just make it a simple function.
It's a bad habit to early-optimise using memoisation in this way, as the added complexity can add bugs (like the one you're seeing), but also if incorrectly set up, can return out-of-date or incorrect info.

If you don't mind the data getting stale, and there's a genuine performance issue, then you can use it, but remember to include the telephone number state variable into the dependencies array at the end. [See here for docs on the proper usage](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback).

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to use the useRef() Hook, particularly since it is guaranteed to be preserved between renders, rather than createRef() - I do this fairly frequently.

Equally, as a good design practice, I would *think* you want to de-couple the telephone input and the button click - I would take advantage of the useState() hook to update the telephone number onChange() of that input, and reference the state value in the fetch - something like (warning: untested code)

```
const [ telephone, setTelephone] = useState("");

const UpdateUsers = () => {
    database.collection('UsuariosDev')
    .where('Telefono', '==', telephone)
    .get()
    .then(response => {
        const fetchedUsers = [];
        response.forEach(document => {
            const fetchedUser = {
                ...document.data(),
                id: document.id
            };
            fetchedUsers.push(fetchedUser);
            console.log(fetchedUser)
        });
        setUsers(fetchedUsers);
        if (fetchedUsers.length !== 0) {
            setTitle('✔️')
        } else {
            setTitle('❌')
        }
    })
};

<input
  onchange={e => setTelephone(e.target.val())}
  type="tel"
  placeholder="Número de teléfono"
/>

<button
  onClick={UpdateUsers}
  className="btn btn-default">
  Comprobar teléfono
</button>
```